# com.google.protobuf.nano does not exist

Tags: android

Trying to build Launcher3 from source, but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Error:(9, 31) error: package com.google.protobuf.nano does not exist
```

Any help out there?

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.launcher3"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you give us more details please?
May we have a look to your gradle files? By the way, did you checked this issue? https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/956

Answer (score 0):

`apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'` just worked for me. I am using the latest release (as of today) and it worked perfectly.